# Como depurar um site em dispositivos móveis?

Tags: cross-browser, debug, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo um site que, embora fique bem no desktop, está ficando desformatado quando acessado via dispositivos móveis. Especificamente, alguns problemas ocorrem quando usado o *browser* padrão do Android, outros quando usado o Chrome pro Android. Não tenho acesso a outros aparelhos para testar (iPhone, etc).

Para depurar no desktop, em geral basta usar as próprias ferramentas do *browser* (tipo "Inspecionar Elemento"), mas não há algo equivalente que eu saiba nesses dispositivos. Eu vejo o elemento fora do lugar, mas não consigo imaginar por que... (e o site ainda usa vários plugins de terceiros, o que complica um bocado a tarefa)

Existem ferramentas para auxiliar na depuração de sites para dispositivos móveis? De preferência algo que eu possa instalar no desktop, sem precisar ter acesso ao dispositivo de fato. Eu cheguei a instalar o Android numa máquina virtual, o que não ajuda muito, pois ainda carece de meios para fazer a depuração. Como isso normalmente é feito?

Comment: O device mode do google chrome tu já usou?

Comment: @haykou Não conhecia não, parece muito bom! Valeu, vou experimentar aqui

Comment: Uma opção fantástica no chrome para Android é o [Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging).

Answer (score 1):

Bom, te aconselho a baixar o Firefox Developer Edition o logan deles é "Feito para aqueles que fazem a Web,Apresentamos o único navegador feito especialmente para desenvolvedores como você." segue o link: [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/developer/)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a opção no próprio google chrome na barra de opções ao lado de **Elements**.

**Device mode.**

Você pode debugar e visualizar seu site em vários dispositivos.
Os emuladores nunca serão 100% mas eu utilizo um tempo e ajuda bastante, na hora dos testes.

Answer (score 1):

Se a depuração for de apenas javascript pode usar o http://jsconsole.com/